help with installing sage-math
So I wanted to use SageMath and I went to their website. They say that Linux binaries have been discontinued and windows support has been stopped.

I am on Windows 10 and I referred to the WSL installation. 
They ask us to ensure that we are running WSL 2 and so I am (I checked by typing "wsl -l -v" in powershell.
Then they have the following three commands:

curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
 bash Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
 conda create -n sage sage python=3.11

The first one goes through with some installation. The second one makes us read some stuff and type "yes".
The third one is where I have the issue. After the second one, it displayed the following message:
Transaction starting 

Transaction finished

To activate this environment, use:

    micromamba activate /home/somudog/miniforge3

Or to execute a single command in this environment, use:

    micromamba run -p /home/somudog/miniforge3 mycommand

installation finished.
Do you wish to update your shell profile to automatically initialize conda?
This will activate conda on startup and change the command prompt when activated.
If you'd prefer that conda's base environment not be activated on startup,
   run the following command when conda is activated:

conda config --set auto_activate_base false

You can undo this by running `conda init --reverse $SHELL`? [yes|no]
[no]

I typed yes assuming it will auto-install. Then some no change no change messages appeared with the warnings -
WARNING conda.common.path.windows:_path_to(100): cygpath is not available, fallback to manual path conversion
WARNING conda.common.path.windows:_path_to(100): cygpath is not available, fallback to manual path conversion

The third command doesnt work because conda is apparently not a command.
P.s. - I have no experience with Linux at all so if you try to explain some shell stuff, I won't get it anyways ...
